# Render a jsf element on mouseover

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a `<h:panelGrid>` and a `h:commandLink`(link is basically a image).Now I want that on mouseover event , Then link should be render`(render='true')` and on mouseout event, it gets removed `render='false'`.
But I am unable to create the logic that How can I do this with these events as the approach I am using is To set the values of bean `true` and `false` on this event.
Here is my code

```
<h:form>
        <h:panelGrid mouseover='** we cannot call a bean method here which changes the bean value **'>

        This is the Div On which I want to apply mouseover event
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:commandLink id="btn" render={renderBean.renderLink}>
        <h:graphicImage url="image.jpg"/>
        </h:commandLink>


    </h:form>
```

The default value of `renderLink` attribute of `renderBean` is false. *Now I want to know the way that How can I change its value to `true` on mouseover event?* Is it possible? **OR** Anyother solution in JSF w.r.t this requirement

Comment: What's the motivation of showing/hiding the link in the `onmouseover`/`onmouseleft` events? Please explain your functional requirement to have better guidance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember in JSF that the page will first be processed server-side by the JSF engine in the web server.  At that time all JSF tags will be converted into their HTML equivalent.  The `render` attribute tells the server-side engine whether or not to output an HTML `a` (anchor) link in the place of the `<h:commandLink>` element.

The behavior you're looking for, namely responding to mouse events, is client-side functionality.  It happens in the browser, not at the web server, so no JSF is involved.  The solution is to handle the mouse events in JavaScript, not JSF.  You will typically set (or remove) the CSS attribute `display:none` on the id called `btn` (unfortunately it's slightly more complex as JSF will mangle the element id a bit).  There are lots of posts here on StackOverflow that deal with how to handle client-side events in JavaScript.  Using jQuery for example is a really common approach.

I recommend to get started you take a look at the blog of one of our best JSF resources and long-time StackOverflow user BalusC: http://balusc.blogspot.com.

There's a lot to learn and you'll get a good start by going there first (and searching for his posts on SO).

Good luck.